# How to add a login to sysadmin role in sql 2014 using script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have tried all the solutions I could find online including similar ones in stackoverflow and none of them helped. 
When i tried

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [name]
```

i get this error:
*Keyword or statement option 'role' is not supported in this version of SQL Server*

the stored proc *sp_addsrvrolemember* does not exist in SQL 2014. 
Is there any other way i can add a login to sysadmin role?

Comment: You add a Login to a server role not a user.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the same. 'writing 'username' in the script might have been confusing. Will modify. Do you know how to do it via script?

Comment: The only way I know is using the `sp_addsrvrolemember`, I would suggest doing it by SSMS and script it out, see what SQL Server is doing behind the scene to actually accomplish it.

Comment: This sounds like you are on Azure SQL Database, not SQL Server 2014. Does `SELECT @@VERSION;` yield `Microsoft SQL Azure...`? If so, you can't add a login to `sysadmin` because there is no such concept in Azure SQL Database - your permissions are contained to your database, not the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron was right (his answer is a comment to my question). I was trying to do this in SQL Azure. This is not supported and only way to change the admin password is by resetting the password from Azure management portal or REST commands.